# FirebaseAdmin messaging returning 404 not found

Tags: asp.net, .net, firebase, asp.net-core, firebase-admin

I am writing an API that sends an firebase message (using the official FirebaseAdmin library) when requested to a android device. I got it working perfect in normal C#, but in ASP.NET core **I always get a 404 not found exception.**

```
Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (NotFound)
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "notFound"
      }
    ],
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
```

I run the following code at startup:

```
if (FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance == null)
{
    FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions
    {
        Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile($@"{env.WebRootPath}\app-5a821-firebase-adminsdk-pf36f-6f44114d87.json")
    });
}
```

And this is the request that I made, very simple:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>>> Get()
{
    var message = new Message
    {
        Token = "dgY8UMXhEZ4:APA91bFnrZTGJKkCCBJHzbghvsvEaq-w-ee1XBAVqAaS-rsmR3Ald23rHGgpfdgVb09r97jDQBVSc6GtDHWtLHWAnn4Lm3EM_j-sh7cu-RaRSrfnk3X124v4co3Q9ID6TxFdGgv7OXWt",
        Data = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"title", "test" }
        }
     };
     try
     {
        var fcmResult = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message);
     } catch (FirebaseException ex)
     {

     } 

     return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
 }
```

Github test project: https://github.com/kevingoos/FirebaseAdminTest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved problem: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-dotnet/issues/73

This happens when the token is invalid/expired or does not belong to the same project as the credentials used to initialize the Admin SDK.